# Наследование ячеек таблицы

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Проблема заключается в том, что по макету у всех `tr` задан линейный градиент в `background`. Но если задаешь самой строчке этот самый градиент, то все `td` наследуют от него этот бг. Пробовал для ячеек отключить наследование значением `initial`, но как видно не работает. Пробовал сделать бг у ячеек прозрачным, тоже не работает. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

```css
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #60625e;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  background-image: linear-gradient(122deg, rgba(200,200,200,.1), rgba(213,213,213,.1) 22%, rgba(255,255,255,.1));
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px;
  background: initial;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="block">
    <th colspan="2">Метраж квартиры</th>
    <td>От 30 м.кв</td>
    <td>От 40 м.кв.</td>
    <td>От 60 м.кв.</td>
    <td>От 80 м.кв.</td>
    <td>От 100 м.к.</td>
    <td colspan="1">Больше 120 м.кв.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Ваш CSS приведите в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил и также более подробно описал.

Comment: Зачем добавлять стиль для `tr`, а потом перекрывать фон у ячеек? Как выглядит макет?

Comment: Cтранно как то. а `td{ background: none !important; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ниже картинка в вопросе - это макет? Дак тут у вас у каждой ячейки свой градиент да и все...

```css
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #60625e;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(122deg, rgba(200, 200, 200, .1), rgba(213, 213, 213, .1) 22%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Метраж квартиры</td>
    <td>От 30 м.кв</td>
    <td>От 40 м.кв.</td>
    <td>От 60 м.кв.</td>
    <td>От 80 м.кв.</td>
    <td>От 100 м.к.</td>
    <td colspan="1">Больше 120 м.кв.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Неидеально, но вариант (правда не могу разобраться почему у средних ячеек тень темнее):

```css
table {
  width: 90vw;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 5vw;
}
tr {
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
td {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), white .5em, white 2.5em, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1));
}
tr td:first-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), transparent .5em, transparent), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), white .5em, white 2.5em, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05));
  border-radius: .25em 0 0 .25em;
}
tr td:last-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), transparent .5em, transparent), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), white .5em, white 2.5em, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05));
  border-radius: 0 .25em .25em 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1
    </td>
    <td>2
    </td>
    <td>2
    </td>
    <td>3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1
    </td>
    <td>2
    </td>
    <td>2
    </td>
    <td>3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Это готовое уже. Сам макет вот
![](https://pp.vk.me/c636821/v636821087/3db5b/m5TwN54zvhY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо, чтобы градиент растягивался на весь `tr`, то добавьте код:

```
tr {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```